# Unexpected 960.gs framework behavior

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

This is my first post on stackoverflow; please let me know if this question is poorly posed.

I am new to html/css and am experimenting with 960 gs stylesheets.  What follows is the html code I'm confused about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
            <title>This is the title</title>
                <link href="css/960template/960.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/960template/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link href="css/960template/text.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="containter_12">
            <div class="grid_1">
                <p>
                    Here's some text. It should create a new line after 60px but its not. In fact, it will fill the breadth of the page before starting on a new line.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_11">
                <p>
                    More text.  Even more to make this line longer to test the limits of this box.       
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I expect this code to display is the first paragraph element in a box one column wide and the second in one that is eleven columns wide.  What actually happens is that the boxes stretch to accommodate each element's contents until the edge of the page is reached. It does not seem as though the problem lies in how my directory is structured. Am I doing something wrong? Have I misunderstood how this template works? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What is your CSS for these classes?

Comment: The CSS for the classes in the HTML documents is in the 960.css file downloaded from the official 960.gs website. Here's the code in the actual selectors:                                                                              .container_12 .grid_1 {
  width: 60px;
}                                                                                          .container_12 .grid_11 {
  width: 860px;
}